# How test Management Notification in Mule?

Tags: notifications, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am working on mule project where I need to create a notification for mule management.
I created a Mule notification as follows:

```
<notifications>
    <notification event="MANAGEMENT"/>
    <notification-listener ref="managementNotificationsListener"/>
</notifications>
```

Beans are as follows:

```
<bean name="managementNotificationsListener" class="org.company.listeners.MuleManagementNotificationListener"/>
```

java class is as follows:

```
public class MuleManagementNotificationListener implements ManagementNotificationListener<ManagementNotification> {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void onNotification(ManagementNotification arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("***********************************\n\n\n\n"
                + "  Manage Processer notification"
                + "\n\n\n\n************************************");
    }

}
```

Now I don't know how to test if this is working, Please if anybody has worked on this area or have knowledge please help me out.

Comment: Do you know what a Management Notification is and when it triggers? What are you expecting to receive from this notification exactly?

Comment: This looks to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve.